# VBA HTML Adressing with .getElements

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have following HTML

[image]

and I am trying to get the highlighted Date.

This is my code but it doesn't work. I get

> "object doesnt support this property or method" :

```
Set sammel = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date").innerText
```

Here is the complete Code

```
Sub testalt()

Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLInput2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim buttonsubmit As HTMLButtonElement
Dim sammel As String

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://plm.corp.int/&showInitialResults=true&cancelLabel=Close&minRequiredChars=3&genericDelete=true&selection=multiple&txtTextSearch=e2711846&filters={%27txtTextSearch%27:[%27Equals|e2711846%27]}
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

'Seite öffnen und Wert in Suche geben
Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtTextSearch")
Set HTMLInput2 = HTMLDoc.getElementById("mx_btn-search")
HTMLInput.Value = "e2711846"
HTMLInput.FireEvent ("onkeyup")
HTMLInput2.Click

''Nach neuester Version suchen

sammel = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date")(0).innerText

End Sub
```

sammel remains empty. can there be a problem with my page not refreshing or something ? Because im opening a search windows, then typing in the searchterm and searching for it. but the URL remains the same in the newly opened window. It is a javascript thingy i think

Comment: Check out `Debug.Print HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date").Length` if it is zero that means there is no `class` named `date` found. Why do you use `InternetExplorerMedium` and not `InternetExplorer`? check if that works too.

Comment: regarding the InternetexplorerMedium. If i dont use that, i get run-time error 462. Debugprint gives me "0"

Comment: Zero means there is nothing found by `getElementsByClassName("date")`. Since your URL is not public available that is all we can tell, and we are not able to reproduce your issue. So you probably need to investigate more to give more details or find your issue on your own.

Comment: Could it be that when you do `HTMLInput2.Click`, the browser loads a new webpage? something like search results, or info abouta product and so on. If true, that means the source code changed, and your variable `HTMLDoc` is still linked to **first** webpage. So you would need to repeat the process (link it to new loaded webpage, and get elements in the source code)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns i tried some stuff now and changed my code. i am not directly navigating to the "exxx" number i want, avoiding the search function. So i guess it shouldnt be an HTMLDoc issue. but whatever i try. i still get the same runtime error

Comment: Try to wait after `HTMLInput2.Click` until `ie.readyState` is `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` using a loop like you did in the beginning. Maybe it needs some time to load something and the HTML code is not ready yet.

Comment: Also, make sure the code is in the main webpage, and **not** inside an frame/iframe, because then in VBA you need first to get the frame and later on the HTMLDoc element from that frame.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns you might have a point with that frame thing. i just checked the html code. how do i adress the frame first?

Comment: Something like `Set MyFrame = HTMLDoc.Frames(0).document` should get you the frame's htmldoc. If there is more than 1 frame, you'll need to get the right one with the index

Answer (score 1):

There can exist more than one HTML tag that has a `class="date"` so `HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date")` is an array of these elements.

If you assume multiple elements with `class="date"` you need to loop through them. Or you can get the first of them by using:

```
Dim sammel As Object
Set sammel = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date")(0)
Debug.Print sammel.innerText
```

Note that you can only `Set` an object but `innerText` returns a string (text). So either something like the above one or without `Set`

```
Dim sammel As String
sammel = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Just wondering and not sure but if `innertext` returns a string, why the `Set`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns OMG, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. I improved my answer.

Comment: @ anonymous down voter without leaving a comment: very useful!

Comment: Thx guys. I will try it out tomorrow and report back

Comment: Unfortunately i am still getting an error. Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @DimitriosTop Please edit your original question show the relevant code you have (see [mcve]) so we can reproduce the issue and tell in which line of code you get this error. This is the only way we can help you.

Comment: updated it. please check. Error is in the last line of code